# Change only pair or unpair divs from a container

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make pair or unpair divs from a container to have a different background. For example the first one has a red background, the second blue, the third red the fourth blue and so...

This is my code:

```
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>

div { width:50px; height:50px; background:red; }
```

I really don't know how to achieve this. I don't know if I need only css or jquery too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS by using the `:nth-child` selector:

```
div { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
div:nth-child(odd) { background-color: red; }
div:nth-child(even) { background-color: blue; }
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx24T/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use pseudo selector nth-child of CSS property . By using this u can select odd even node

```
div:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #FF0000; }
div:nth-child(even) { background-color: #0000FF; }
```